# Provide current activity in constructor Dagger

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am new to `Dagger` and it is awesome but I'm having an issue.

Dialog class needs current activity as `context` for initialization.

```
class ProgressUtil @Inject constructor(val context: Activity) {

    var dialog: Dialog? = null

    fun show() {
        hide()

        dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog?.let {
            it.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            it.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog)
            it.setCancelable(false)
            it.show()
        }
    }

    fun hide() {
        dialog?.let {
            if (it.isShowing) {
                it.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `ActivityModules` class

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModules {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity() : MainActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributePostsActivity() : PostsActivity

    // Want to pass current activity as activity param
    @Provides
    fun progressUtilMainActivity(activity: Activity): ProgressUtil = ProgressUtil(activity)

}
```

AppComponent class

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityModules::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: AppController) : Builder

        fun build() : AppComponent

    }

    fun inject(application: AppController)
}
```

Is there a generic way to use progress bar in many activities without creating a module for each activity?